# What is difference between mode and state?

Tags: wireless-networking, optical-media

What is difference between mode and state?

In many article we can see the term use of mode, like sleep mode, deep sleep mode.
then again, we can find state, such as listen state, transmit state and reception state.
I am wondering what the difference between these two (mode and state).

In case of a mobile terminal or a Optical network unit (ONU), the node (MT/ONU) moves into sleep mode. Sleep mode has two states: Listen state and sleep state. In the listen state it scans the beacon message from the BS/Optical Line terminal (OLT), while in the sleep state the radio transceivers are off. Please tell me whether my understanding is right or not.

Comment: This question is really best for english.stackexchange.com, but I have answered it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the contexts you've described, there's not much difference between the word "mode" and "state".

"Mode" is slightly more likely to imply states that the user put the device into, and that the user must take the device out of. Whereas "states" aren't as likely to imply that the user put the devices into that state or that the user is responsible for taking the device out of that state; the software or hardware is more likely to put itself into different states.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So far I understand from your explanation is that: A mobile terminal moves into sleep mode. Sleep mode has two states: Listen state and sleep state. In the listen state it scans the beacon message from the BS, while in the sleep state the radio transivers are off. Please opine if possible.

Comment: @hassan If you have questions about how 802.11 power save mode works, ask them as separate Questions, not as comments to an Answer to a Question that had nothing to do with 802.11.

Answer (score 1):

`Mode` is really an option allowing a change in the method of operation of a device. `State` is an noun which expresses the current status (or condition) of something which can sometimes be affected by the `mode` of a device.